# Visual Studio for Mac won't update - Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-macros

Weird issue here.  I have Visual Studio for Mac.  My mac is fully upto date on the mac sidel.  I have updated to Xcode 12.5.  I have selected the check for updates option in VSMac.  I see that there are a bunch of updates for xamarin on my mac.  I selected for it to update and restart, and then nothing happens.  VSMac just closes.  I'm assuming I have something on my system that VSMac doesn't like.  Is there a way to just get the downloads and manually install them?

Answer (score 0):

Here was the way that I solved the problem.  I went and downloaded the various pieces that I knew I had specific problems with.  This was VSMac, Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Mac.  I downloaded those, and then installed the iOS and Mac versions.  Everything was still good.  Then I installed the most up to date VSMac.  It detected the old versions of Mono, Android, and some other stuff, and downloaded and installed them.  Now, my current problem is solved.  There may still be others, but this got my immediate problem resolved.

Hopefully, this helps someone else in the future.